# TensorFlow Adding C++ Gradient for a Custom Op

Tags: c++, tensorflow, operators, gradient, loss

I'm currently working on a project where I have to add a custom loss function to the tensorflow (1.13.1) C++ API. This function relies on some external libraries, so my idea was to add this loss function as a custom op. I tried to follow this guide https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/create_op but the most important part about adding the gradient in C++ is missing. 
So here is what I have done so far:

I started with registering two new ops in `nn_ops.cc`, one for the loss function `MyLoss` and another one for calculating the gradient `MyLossGrad`. In the next step I implemented both ops in `myloss_op.cc` following the tensorflow guide.

My problem now: How to implement the corresponding gradient? I've registered it in `nn_grad.cc` and pass predictions and target labels to `MyLoss` op:

```
Status MyLossGrad(const Scope& scope, const Operation& op,
                  const std::vector<Output>& grad_inputs,
                  std::vector<Output>* grad_outputs) {     

  auto y_pred = op.input(0);   // Predictions passed to MyLoss Op
  auto y_true = op.input(1);   // Target labels passed to MyLoss Op

  auto my_loss = op.output(0);   // Calculated Loss from my MyLoss Op

  // Do I need these?
  auto grad_loss = grad_inputs[0];  
  auto grad_grad = grad_inputs[1];

  // Calculate and pass gradient
  auto dx = internal::MyLossGrad(scope, y_pred , y_true);
  grad_outputs->push_back(dx);
  grad_outputs->push_back(NoGradient());    

  return scope.status();   
}
REGISTER_GRADIENT_OP("MyLoss", MyLossGrad);
```

**Intuition**

This is the part where I'm not sure how to continue.
If I got it right I have to calculate two gradients since I have two inputs:

1. dL/dx -> My loss function differentiated wrt. my predictions
2. dL/dy -> My loss function differentiated wrt. the target labels

Both gradients then are then passed to `grad_outputs`.
From my understanding the gradient dL/dy is not needed so I pass `NoGradient` instead.

**Questions:**

- Is my intuition from above correct?
- What are the other parameters used for?
- What is grad_inputs? Some other Ops multiply it with their gradients? Is this required for backpropagation?

I don't know if this matters, but this op is meant to be only used as a loss function and not as an inside node of the graph.

Here is a small snippet how I use the op and train my network:

```
// Build Network:
auto input_x = Placeholder(t_scope.NewSubScope("Input_X"), DT_FLOAT, Placeholder::Shape({bs, x, y, z, c}));
auto input_y = Placeholder(t_scope.NewSubScope("Input_Y"), DT_FLOAT, Placeholder::Shape({bs, x, y, z, c}));

TensorShape filter_size({3, 3, 3, 1, 5});
c_var = Variable(layer_scope.WithOpName("c_var"), filter_size, DT_FLOAT);
c_assign = Assign(layer_scope.WithOpName("c_assign"), c_var , RandomNormal(layer_scope, {3, 3, 3, 1, 5}, DT_FLOAT));   
auto conv = Conv3D(t_scope.NewSubScope("Conv"), input_x, c_var, gtl::ArraySlice<int>{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, "SAME"); 


// Build Optimization Graph: 
auto loss = MyLoss(t_scope.NewSubScope("MyLoss"), conv, input_y);

vector<Output> grad_outputs;
TF_CHECK_OK(AddSymbolicGradients(t_scope, {loss}, {c_var}, &grad_outputs));

auto m_var = Variable(t_scope, m_shapes[i], DT_FLOAT);
auto v_var = Variable(t_scope, m_shapes[i], DT_FLOAT);
auto m_assign = Assign(t_scope, m_var, Input::Initializer(0.f, filter_size)));
auto v_assign = Assign(t_scope, v_var, Input::Initializer(0.f, filter_size)));    
auto adam = ApplyAdam(t_scope, c_var, m_var, v_var, 0.f, 0.f, 0.001f, 0.9f, 0.999f, 0.00000001f, {grad_outputs[0]});
out_grads.push_back(adam.operation);

// Initialize: 
auto t_session = unique_ptr<ClientSession>(new ClientSession(t_scope));
TF_CHECK_OK(t_session->Run({c_assign, m_assign, v_assign}, nullptr));

// Train:
std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
TF_CHECK_OK(t_session->Run(
                    {{input_x, x_tensor}, {input_y, y_tensor}},
                    {loss}, out_grads, &outputs));
```